# Flutter AnimatedSwitcher rebuilds everytime I enter into a textfield

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

In the following code I want the Text under AnimatedSwitcher to animate only when the FlatButton is Pressed, but it animates for every single character that I enter in the TextField. Since the TextField has a setState in its onChanged method, the animation is being triggered each time a character is entered.

How to prevent the AnimatedSwitcher to rebuild every time a setState method is called and to be rebuilt only when the value of its child has been updated?

```
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int _value = 0;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Text(_counter.toString(),
                key: UniqueKey(), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
              return FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: ScaleTransition(
                  scale: animation.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed
                      ? Tween<double>(begin: .5, end: 1).animate(animation)
                      : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1.0),
                  child: child,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text(
              _value.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = int.parse(val) * 5;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter amount"),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                _counter = int.parse(controller.text) * 5;
              }),
              child: Text('Tap to change value'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class _TestScreenState extends State<TestScreen> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int _value = 0;
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: Text(_counter.toString(), key: ValueKey<int>(_counter), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50)),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
              return FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: ScaleTransition(
                  scale: animation.status == AnimationStatus.dismissed
                      ? Tween<double>(begin: .5, end: 1).animate(animation)
                      : AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1.0),
                  child: child,
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text(
              _value.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _value = int.parse(val) * 5;
                });
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Enter amount"),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => setState(() {
                _counter = int.parse(controller.text) * 5;
              }),
              child: Text('Tap to change value'),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But now the non-animated Text Widget doesn't update the value accordingly. I want the second text to update value as I am entering the the amount in the Textfield and the animated text to be updated only when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Romit can you explain more

Comment: When I enter 1 in the Textfield Widget I want the Text Widget to show 5 times the entered amount so in onChanged method of the Textfield I added a setState that multiplies the entered value times 5. But the Animated Text Widget should still show 1 and only when I click the FlatButton I want the Animated Text Widget to update to 5. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, assigning the key value did the trick for me. key: ValueKey<int>(_counter),